# How to find remaining time - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time, timestamp

Let's say my event started at

```
publishDateTime: "2021-08-23T16:45:53.378"
```

and its going to end in duration days,

```
duration: 3
```

How to find the total remaining time?

```
function timer(endTime = "2021-08-27T16:45:53.378") {
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;

  let end = new Date(endTime).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function () {
      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        timeLeft = end - now;

      let days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (day)),
        hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (day)) / (hour)),
        minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (hour)) / (minute)),
        seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (minute)) / second);

      console.log('Time left:' + days + "Days " + hours + "Hrs " + minutes + "Mins " + seconds + "secs")

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        console.log('Times up');
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, 1000)                    // time refresh in ms
}

timer("2021-08-23T16:45:53.378")
```

I'm trying like this, but here I don't know how to convert duration days to timestamp or this kinda format. But when I try endTime with this format it is working. But I've days count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add number of days to your `endDate`

Something like this:

```js
function timer(endTime, durationDay = 3) {
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;

  let endDate = new Date(endTime);
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+durationDay);
  
  let end = endDate.getTime();
  let x = setInterval(function () {
      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        timeLeft = end - now;

      let days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (day)),
        hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (day)) / (hour)),
        minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (hour)) / (minute)),
        seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (minute)) / second);

      console.log('Time left:' + days + "Days " + hours + "Hrs " + minutes + "Mins " + seconds + "secs")

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        console.log('Times up');
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, 1000)                    // time refresh in ms
}

timer("2021-08-23T16:45:53.378")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ah57nypq/

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the remainining time:

```js
const publishDateTime = "2021-08-23T16:45:53.378";
const duration = 3; // days

const durationMs = duration * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
const startDateTime = new Date(publishDateTime);
const endDateTime = new Date(startDateTime.valueOf() + durationMs);
const now = new Date();
const remainingTimeMs = Math.max(0, Math.min(endDateTime.valueOf() - now.valueOf(), durationMs));
console.log(`Remaining time: ${remainingTimeMs} ms`);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you get the time 3 days from now is by getting the current time with `new date()` and adding 3 days to it (calculated from the number of hours, minutes etc.).  I've modified your code to work like this.

```js
function timer(endDays = 1) {
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;

  let end = new Date().getTime() + endDays * day,
    x = setInterval(function () {
      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        timeLeft = end - now;

      let days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (day)),
        hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (day)) / (hour)),
        minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (hour)) / (minute)),
        seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (minute)) / second);

      console.log('Time left:' + days + "Days " + hours + "Hrs " + minutes + "Mins " + seconds + "secs")

      if (timeLeft < 0) {
        console.log('Times up');
        clearInterval(x);
      }
    }, 1000)                    // time refresh in ms
}

timer(3)
```

Comment: Your answer is good too, but for something starting today and End up `endDays` after today. But what about a refresh page or navigator failed. The timers will reset.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I misunderstood your question. The only modification would be to add a publishDateTime param to the timer function and use that instead of new Date().